# Why is my user ID undefined when passing it into my URL?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am building a profile page and trying to get the authenticated user data to display there.  My API call works with their id, and it works on the front end if I manually enter the id into the url.

But when I try to navigate to the profile from the navbar, I receive a

```
400 Bad Request for URL: http://localhost:3000/users/undefined
```

What I can assume right now is that it's an asynchrony issue.  My profile page calls the user data, but that user data isn't available in my nav component.  And it seems as though I need to pass in my id param into my profile [routerLink] if I want to navigate correctly.  Since my user data isn't available in my nav component, it has nothing to pass.

Is there a better approach to this?  Should I be using an event emitter?

Fairly new to Angular - help much appreciated!

## Profile Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '.././services/auth.service';
import { UserService } from '.././services/user.service'
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUser;

  isAuth: boolean;

  constructor(
    private session: AuthService,
    private router:  Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute

  ) {


  this.session.isAuth
       .subscribe((isAuth: boolean) => {
       // user will be false if logged out
       // or user object if logged in.
         this.isAuth = isAuth;
       });
   if (this.session.token) {
     this.isAuth = true;
     console.log(this.session);
   } else {
     this.isAuth = false;
   }

  }




  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.getUserDetails(params['id']);
    });


  }

  getUserDetails(id) {
     this.userService.get(id)
       .subscribe((user) => {
         this.currentUser = user;
         console.log(this.currentUser);
       });
   }


  }
```

## Nav Template

Where I'm navigating to my profile page.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">bnb</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


        <li *ngIf="!isAuth"><a [routerLink]="['login']">Login</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="isAuth"><a [routerLink]="['profile']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Profile</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="isAuth"><a (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="!isAuth"><a [routerLink]="['signup']">Signup</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

## Nav Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '.././services/auth.service';
import { UserService } from '.././services/user.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  isAuth: boolean;

  currentUser: any;


  constructor(
    private session: AuthService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {

    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("User"))
    console.log("USER",this.currentUser)                       //Currently returns Null
    console.log(this.session)
    this.session.isAuth
      .subscribe((isAuth: boolean) => {
      // user will be false if logged out
      // or user object if logged in.
        this.isAuth = isAuth;
      });
  if (this.session.token) {
    this.isAuth = true;
  } else {
    this.isAuth = false;
  }
}

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  logout() {
   this.session.logout();

 }




}
```

## Router

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from '../signup/signup.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
import { RentalListingsComponent } from '../rental-listings/rental-listings.component';
import { SingleRentalComponent } from '../rental-listings/single-rental/single-rental.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from '../profile/profile.component'
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';


export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
    { path: 'rentals', component: RentalListingsComponent },
    { path: 'listing', component: SingleRentalComponent },
    { path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] }   <--profile path.  I know I have to match my url paths, but don't know how to do this from the navbar.  
    // { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] },

    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Comment: looking at your code, I don't see the `users` path defined neither in the routes nor in the template (html) code.

Comment: Do I need to define that path in Angular 2 if I'm using it for my API call?  When I use that path (with the actual user id) in Express it returns the JSON data.  Do I have to match the paths in the front and back?  I receive the user data as well if I manually put in the id into my profile (front-end) path.

Comment: If you're trying to get a query string, try using the getting the id from the `routerState` like so:  `this.router.routerState.root.params.subscribe(data => console.log(data['id']));` If you're using a parameter (e.g. `serverUrl/profile/14`), then make sure your route is formatted as such `this.router.navigate(['/profile', id]);` (not a query string param).

Comment: @universesurfer no you don't. However, you do need to show the api call if you are having problems with the api call. You seem to have forgotten to include the UserService or something to that effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing the detail.  Somewhere you need to subscribe to 'after login' or 'authentication' event, grab the user profile JSON, and save it to localstorage so you can use it anywhere you want.  If you can't hook in or subscribe to one of these, then do it imperatively somewhere convenient in your code.  Find out what call you can make to fetch the entire user JSON and save it as follows...

Check out my AuthService init() below.  First line is `this.authProvider.on('authenticated', this.onAuth);`.  Whatever authentication service API you are using should provide a way for you to specify a callback (providing the login token) whenever someone logs in.  The `onAuth` callback function saves the token in localstorage and then `fetchProfile(...){...}` makes another call to the authentication service API to get the whole JSON user profile using the token just received `this.user.getProfile(idToken, this.onProfile);`.  For example, I use Auth0 in projects, and my call to Auth0 API looks like `this.lock.getProfile(idToken, this.onProfile);` but I replaced that with an example of what your call might look like `this.user.getProfile(idToken, this.onProfile);`  So use whatever your API uses replace in fetchProfile.  Then the `onProfile` callback saves the entire JSON profile in a single key in local storage using `this.localStorage.set('profile', profile);`  Then you can get it any time by calling `this.localStorage.get('profile')`.

1. Do not provide UserService through the lazy-loaded ProfileComponent.  That creates a separate branch on the dependency injection tree you might not want.  See https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/shared-modules-di.html  Import the UserService in a top-level module like AppModule or SharedModule and provide it there.  No need to export it if it's in AppModule.

app.module.ts

```
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    UserService,
    ...
    ]
  providers: [
    ...
    UserService,
    ...
    ]
```

2. Handle Auth related stuff in Auth, not Profile.  Profile seems visual/implementation-specific (e.g. it has a template).  Here is a code snippet example.

auth.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class Auth {

  userProfile: UserProfile;

  constructor(
              ...
              private localStorage: LocalStorageService,
              private router: Router,
              private user: UserService,
              private authProvider: ...
              ...
              ) {
  }

  init() { 
      this.authProvider.on('authenticated', this.onAuth);
      // Set userProfile attribute if already saved profile
      this.userProfile = this.localStorage.get('profile');
      setTimeout(() => { // let AppComponent listener initialize
        this.localStorage.set('profile', this.userProfile);
      }, 0);
    }
  }

  onAuth = (authResult: AuthResult) => {
    this.localStorage.set('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    this.fetchProfile(authResult.idToken);
  }

  // Save current route for redirect url
  login() {
    this.localStorage.set('redirect_url', this.router.url);
    this.authProvider.show({initialScreen: 'login'});
  };

  // Check if user is logged in.
  authenticated() {
    // Check if unexpired token. 
    // Searches for item in localStorage with key == 'id_token'
    return this.authProvider.tokenNotExpired();
  };

  logout() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('');
    this.userProfile = undefined; // do before localstorage
    this.localStorage.remove('id_token');
    this.localStorage.remove('profile');
  };

  fetchProfile(idToken: string) {
    this.user.getProfile(idToken, this.onProfile);
  }

  /**
   * On profile event callback.
   * Save profile to LocalStorage. 
   * Redirect to url if present in LocalStorage.
   */
  onProfile = (error: any, profile: UserProfile) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }
    this.userProfile = profile; 
    this.localStorage.set('profile', profile);

    // Redirect if there is a saved url to do so.
    const redirectUrl: string = this.localStorage.get('redirect_url');
    if (redirectUrl !== undefined) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(redirectUrl);
      this.localStorage.remove('redirect_url');
    }
  }
```

3. Interact with localStorage through a LocalStorageService and subscribe to changes as follows.

localstorage.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {
  [key:string]: any;

  /**
   * define your localstorage variables here as observables
   */
  id_token$ = new Subject();
  redirect_url$ = new Subject();
  profile$ = new Subject();
  customer$ = new Subject();

  set(key: string, value: any) {
    this[key + '$'].next(value); // this will make sure to tell every subscriber about the change.
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }

  get(key: string) {
    const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return value && JSON.parse(value);
  }

  remove(key: string) {
    this[key + '$'].next(undefined);
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
}
```

4. Don't do so much in constructor.  Example:

app.component.ts

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {


    webRobot: boolean = false;

    private profileSub: any;
    private customerSub: any;
    private subscriptionSub: any;

    constructor(
          private analyticsService: AnalyticsService,
          private auth: Auth,
          private localStorage: LocalStorageService,
          ) {
          }

    ngOnInit(): void {
         this.init();
    }

    init() {
        this.auth.init(this.webRobot);
        this.analytics.init(this.webRobot);
        if (!this.webRobot) {
          // subscribe to authed profile changes
          this.profileSub = 
                   this.localStorage.profile$.subscribe(this.onProfile);
          // Subscribe to changes to Stripe customer
          this.customerSub = 
                   this.localStorage.customer$.subscribe(this.onCustomer);
      }


  // always delete active subscribes on destroy
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.profileSub.unsubscribe();
    this.customerSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  onProfile = (profile: UserProfile) => { 

  // ...do stuff        

  }

  onCustomer= (profile: Customer) => {

  // ...do stuff

  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Dan.  I have a lot to learn still about Angular 2.  I was using localStorage before to try to get my authenticated user data, but it looks like it only returns the params I use for login (email, password) and the user token, as opposed to the entire user JSON from the database.  Should I be able to get the mongodb user json from local storage?

Comment: Sure, glad to help.  It helps to see a lot of code examples!   I am going to add some comments to my answer above that might help further.  It's too long to post in a comment :)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It's working!!!  Phew.  For some reason my JSON gets returned in text format as {"key": "value"}, as opposed to a clickable JSON format.  Even after parsing.  Even tried stringifying it first, then parsing.

Comment: Fixed the JSON format issue.  Thanks again for your help!  :D

Answer (score 0):

In your profile route configuration, it is expecting the `id` query param

```
 { path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] }   
<--profile path.  
 I know I have to match my url paths, 
 but don't know how to do this from the navbar.
```

but your navbar link is not passing the id value

```
 <li *ngIf="isAuth"><a [routerLink]="['profile']"><span class="glyphic
```

you need to do something like this in your navbar

```
 <li *ngIf="isAuth"><a [routerLink]="['profile/user.id']">
```

Comment: Thanks Eduardo.  I tried doing that, but the issue seems to be that the user info is not available from the nav component to include in the routerLink url.  I tried making the navbar a child component of profile and passing the user data in, but it remains null.

Comment: so now that you have pinpointed to where the issue is can you remove all the profile code, router code, and provide the component.ts for navbar ?

Comment: I just edited to include the nav component.  I am keeping the other code there now though, for context, as I'm not sure whether the approach I am using is the best one.

Comment: you should probably remove the other ones, its too much code for no reason.